# Android: как у EditText задействовать слушатель, когда он в фокусе?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Мне необходимо, чтобы при расположении курсора (фокус) в поле `EditText` вызывалась определенная функция, например:

```
System.out.println("Hello!!!");
```

Гуглил, читал документацию по `EditText`, но такого метода не нашел.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [`setOnFocusChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29).